# Use C# to open an Excel file and store values into an ArrayList data structure

Tags: c#, excel, arraylist

I am trying to write a program in C# in console mode. What I want to do is load a file in sequential mode from an Excel file using the C#'s System.IO library. This information is to be stored using the ArrayList structure (System.collection library). The Excel file I am using has multiple columns and I want to have the rows to be stored as a record and each record to stored on a separate line.

Comment: Show us where you're at with your current code

Comment: Fine, What are all the issues that you are facing in this? Have you tried anything?